# rclone sync: how to exclude a subdirectory with a certain name

Tags: rclone

I want to exclude a certain subfolder name during sync process as that subdirectory can be stored in different directories.
I tried with this command but it seems it doesn't work as that folder name is not in the root.

```
rclone --exclude /EXAMPLE_TO_EXCLUDE/** --ignore-case --delete-excluded sync -v -P dropbox_an_app: /mnt/user/Dropbox_local/live_sync/AN_Main
```

The problem is that the subfolder "EXAMPLE_TO_EXCLUDE" can be in different folders and not in the root, so that rule is skipped.
In few words, I want to exclude that folder content from syncing disregard where it's.